# How do I change attachment slug from name to id

Tags: url-rewriting, attachments, slug

I need to change the slug of the attachment post. Currently, it is showing attachment name , I want it to be replaced by id of attachment.

Edit :
Thanks to suggestion by TheDeadMedic, I am now seeing urls with their postname changed to id in url (slug of the url.). But somehow it is adding now adding /attachment/ as well to the url right before slug (id). How should I remove this /attachment/ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `add_attachment` hook to update the slug after the attachment has been inserted:

```
function wpse_182454_attachment_id_as_slug( $post_id ) {
    if ( get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id ) != $post_id ) {
        wp_update_post(
            array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_name' => ( string ) $post_id,
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_182454_attachment_id_as_slug' );
```

Comment: thanks its working, but now I am getting /attachment/ before the post_name (which is id now)

Comment: @akshayb, you asked how to replace the slug and you got an answer ;). If you need something else to happen as wel as replacing the slug then please edit the question and state it explicitly.